# Ignore ELPA files in recentf

Tags: emacs, elpa

I update from ELPA/MELPA regularly. Unfortunately, the files the Emacs package manager manipulates show up in my recentf list, basically making it useless since it's always full from whatever files were updated, and not files that I actually care about. How can I fix this?

Comment: It's arguably a bug that those files show up in the recentf list, so you should report it via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See user options `recentf-exclude`, `recentf-keep`, `recentf-auto-cleanup`, and command `recentf-cleanup`.

The first two options let you exclude and include files that satisfy certain predicates or whose names match certain patterns, respectively.

Comment: Thank you. I was being dumb. I did google before I asked, I just didn't find anything.

Comment: Ask Emacs first, before googling: `C-h v recentf TAB`.  Or load library `recentf` and then do `M-x customize-option recentf TAB`.